# Do plants react differently to artificial light than to sunlight?

Tags: indoors, sunlight, light, sunflowers, led

Sun light is 5700Kelvin and up to 100 000 lumens per square meter. If I was to use Halogen or LED light's with similar properties would plants (sunflowers in particular) know the difference?

Comment: I believe the mechanisms of relation between sun and sunflowers in particular are not fully explained yet. Even if you provide the appropriate light, it will not move like sun does, and sunflowers may feel the difference. But I am just a hobbist, you should check more reliable sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of plants are grown under artificial lighting. Plants only need light to power photosynthesis so as long as you provide the correct wavelengths it doesn't really matter to them.

Sunflowers are going to be a problem for you because of their height.  You would be better off growing a dwarf species, and using a reflective grow tent as they do when they grow marijuana illegally as otherwise you're going to need many more lights to give all the leaves good coverage.